# Does a Transparent Firewall need a Default gateway if directly connected to a layer 3 device that is actively performing routing?

Tags: routing, ipv4, firewall, layer3, route

Good folks of the Network Engineering stack!
I have a question that I assume most people could answer in their sleep.  To better illustrate my question, I've provided a sketch of my network below.

In essence, will the Firewall shown in red below allow traffic to the layer 3 switch (192.168.1.1) **?**

Do i need to add a static route on that transparent Firewall for traffic that originates outside of its specific network (192.168.1.1) **?**

I imagine there are two solutions.

1. I would add a route on the transparent firewall
2. I would define the default gateway of the PC (192.168.1.3) as the Layer 3 switch (192.168.1.1)

Are both of these required **?**

Could I get by with just one of these **?**

Does anyone have any good training sites they could send me that could iron out the basics for this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transparent firewall works like a switch - completely transparent to L3/IP. As such, there's no forwarding decision for IP, no routing, and no gateway(s) required.

A transparent firewall doesn't even require an IP address from the filtered network. All you (likely) need is an IP address and possibly routes for management (which should always be on a seperate network with seperate addressing).

In your scenario, the PC would use the L3 switch as (default) gateway, that is correct.

Requests for resources are off-topic here, sorry.